# Code coverage and DMLException - How to enter Exception?

Tags: code-coverage, dmlexception

I insert lists that are created from pre-existing data.

In my `@testSetup` I create the mockup but it's 'impossible' to enter the DMLException when trying to achieve 100% code coverage.

This is my code + code coverage:
[image]

The only solution I found, and that works, is to update my code by creating a new 'artificial' Method to do the insert, and that would be easy to test entering the DMLException.

->
new method :
[image]

Change in the code :
[image]

And in test class :
[image]

It works but isn't there a better way of doing it?

I'm really not found of the idea of add artificial coding to production code, just to get a better coverage...

Comment: Also if you don't want to be down-voted for nothing, remove the word bull**** from the post ;)

Comment: Ohw... I forgot I choose that name, I should have called it dummyClass or whatsoever, you're right

Comment: Posting code screenshots rather than text fragments is also a reason for attracting downvotes. Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour).

Comment: Agreed, it's a shame @identigral, but it's for a superBadge and Salesforce hate to see parts of those code posted...

Comment: Also, this question was more a conceptual one, in my opinion. Not a code particuliar issue, more a general one !

Answer (score 1):

You can try set up invalid lookup key for the case in your `@testSetup`. For example:

```
insert new Case(OwnerId = '005000000000000');
```

This will give you INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY. You can use this mocked userId (key prefix is OK, but the id is actually non-existent).